# More than one custom value accessor on Reactive Form with Material Datepicker and Ngx Mask

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, mask

I am trying to create a Reactive Form with Material Datepicker and Ngx Mask

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{ 'mat-datepicker-opened': picker.opened }">
    <mat-label>Fecha</mat-label>
    <input
    matInput
    formControlName="date"
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    [placeholder]="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
    mask="d0/M0/0000"
    [leadZeroDateTime]="true"
    [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="picker">
    <span
        class="material-symbols-rounded"
        matDatepickerToggleIcon>
        calendar_today
    </span>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But I get this error:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

How I could solve it?

I want to have a Reactive Form with Material Datepicker and Ngx Mask